# Any "lighter" PHP mail alternatives to PHPMailer or Swift Mailer

Tags: email, php

My host doesn't support PHP mail() so I am looking for a PHP mailer.

I have of course come across PHPMailer and Swift Mailer and a couple of others but was hoping there was an alternative that didn't need 34 includes, 145 languages support, and thousands of thousands of lines of code to support every possible feature that anyone might want.

Is there any more minimal PHP mailers out there that maintained similar features to PHP mail() and remote SMTP support?

Comment: I'm wrote my own implementation of the `mail()` command about 15 years ago (still using it in some places), working directly on socket level. Fully "syntax compatible" to PHP's own. Just a ~9k "library" file with no dependencies. It was part of phpGroupware then. Can't find it in its latest (2012) code, and never published it separately – but if that would be what you need, I could put it into a Gist, for example.

Comment: PS: Just found another SMTP class in the sources of ownCloud v7 (in "thirdparty") which additionally supports TLS. It's also a "stand-alone class". Strangely, it seems no longer there with oC 9 (looks like it got rewritten and now has dependencies).

Comment: Please share, Izzy. You never fail to impress me :-)

Comment: Thanks @Izzy, both options sound interesting.

Comment: Actually, the OC one was taken from PHPMailer. Looks like it still has no dependencies and can be used directly, so you could give it a try: [smtp.php](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/SMTP.php). Though from a quick glance I could not figure how to *easily* use that (check the examples). My class on the other hand is easy to deal with: Instantiate it with the server parameters, the call the `smail()` method as you would call `mail()`. [Here's the version from 2003](https://pastebin.com/H94hqRJ3), would need minor adjusts for PHP7 (`__construnct()`).

Comment: PS: If my class works for you and you prefer that over the other one, please let me know. I've just updated the code and included some minor fixes. Easier to configure now, and some missing headers are now taken care for. Let me know if I shall make it an answer then :)

Comment: Your class looks good @Izzy. Haven't managed to successfully send an email yet but still trying. Should lines 67 and 68 be `==` instead of `=`?

Comment: The PHPMailer one looks like just the SMTP part of PHPMailer, and needs the other files (PHPMailer, Exception, etc) to offer similar functionality to mail().

Comment: With your script @Izzy, fsockopen is successful and socket2msg returns a 220 message, but after successfully sending the next HELO command socket2msg returns an empty response and smail() exits unsuccessfully. Any ideas?

Comment: Nope, never had that. Empty message means session over (otherwise it had to be a line starting with 3 digits, like `250 2.1.0 Ok` or `221 2.0.0 Bye`. What mail server is talking at the other end? And yes, you're correct with the `==` (fixed in the "[polished version](https://gist.github.com/IzzySoft/4b1482b1a441393b447ce57874840bfc)").

Comment: I'm not sure what mail server it is. It is part of my hosting plan, and it doesn't say what type of server in the welcome message or response. After connecting it responds with `220 x.x.com is ready and awaiting your commands! Glad to meet you x.x.x.x! How can I help you? The time now is Sun, 29 Oct 2017 22:11:06 +0000 (UTC), ` and then after issuing the `HELO` it runs for 60 seconds and then stops with no response. Does the `,` at the end of the initial response mean anything? (I did try PHPmailer and that does work but 6,000 lines of code!)